# How to populate listview adapter from outside Activity in a TabActivity

Tags: java, android

I have the following problem.

I am in a tabActivity with 2 tabs. Every tab will launch the same activity, but there is a onTabChangeListener.
In this tabchange listener i need to set up the listview adapter that is different for each activity.
So i will have two different lists, and i want to change their adapter from TabActivity, from this onTabchangeListener, but i get the following error: system services not available to activities before oncreate()
The code for tabs is:

```
  host = getTabHost();

    host.addTab(host.newTabSpec(TAG_AVAILABLE).setIndicator("First Tab")
            .setContent(new Intent(this, MyActivity.class)));
    host.addTab(host.newTabSpec(TAG_DOWNLOAD).setIndicator("Second Tab ")
            .setContent(new Intent(this, MyActivity.class)));
    host.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String s) {
            MyActivity myActivity = new MyActivity();
            int i = getTabHost().getCurrentTab();
            if (i == FIRST_TAB) {
                setAdapterForMyActivity(firstAdapter);       
            }
            }
            if (i == SECOND_TAB) {
                 setAdapterForMyActivity(secondAdapter);        
            }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

The main question is how to set adapter of an listView which is in an Activity from TabActivity.
Thank you very much.

Comment: do not set the adapter just initialize the adapter and set that adapter in oncreate of the Activity

Comment: show the full code of Activity.

Comment: You can't ever make this call: `MyActivity myActivity = new MyActivity();`. The only way to get an Activity is when the OS creates it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass an Adapter to a child activity, you'll need a global shared object of some kind. One option would be to pass the adapter to an Application object in the parent TabActivity and then retrieve that in the child activity.